# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use the Bing api.  Problem is I keep getting an error of "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."  Specifically at the JObject.Parse

Here is my code:

```
        public async Task<CoordServiceResult> LookUp()
    {

        var result = new CoordServiceResult();
        var location = "seattle";           
        var key = "MyBingKey"
        var url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=" + location + "&output=xml&key=" + key;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        var results = JObject.Parse(json);
        var resources = results["resourceSet"][0]["resources"];
        var coords = resources[0]["geocodePoints"][0]["coordinates"];

        result.Lat = (double)coords[0];
        result.Long = (double)coords[1];

        return result;
    }
```

I was also looking at this link [Error Parsing Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869119/error-parsing-json-values-in-asp-net-mvc) but it didnt work either.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the data as XML not JSON.

```
&output=xml
```

Remove this parameter to get a JSON response.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx states a JSON response is provided when the output (o) parameter is not set.